# Civirules send email action creates activity in UTC time

Tags: civicase, civirules, activity

I have a rule with the trigger "Case activity is added". This activity is an "Alert" activity, and when is created, the action "Send E-mail to contacts on a case", sends it to supervisor roles in that case.

However as you can see in the attached image, while the Alert is created in the right local time, the sent email is registered with +4 hours (so I think is UTC time because we are in America/Santiago).

[image: Send email activity created by CiviRules with +4 hours or UTC time]

I'm on wordpress and sure that is correctly set in America/santiago in CMS. Also I have set that as Default timezone in php.ini.

Using Civicrm 5.36.0, Wordpress 5.7, CiviRules 2.24, and E-Mail API 2.2

Any help or guidance will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like it might be a bug in CiviRules. I suggest that you [raise an issue](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/civirules/-/issues).

Looking at the issues, [#127](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/civirules/-/issues/127) might be related.